# Godot: Texture painting

Tags: godot

I would like to make a texture painter in Godot, and I found that one of the steps to doing this is using a blit_rect. I could not find any docs or anything about the blit_rect online, so it would be great if someone could inform me about how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to write an answer for this got a bit out of hand for me. So I'm going to give you a couple references: https://github.com/alfredbaudisch/GodotRuntimeTextureSplatMapPainting - https://alfredbaudisch.com/blog/gamedev/godot-engine/godot-engine-in-game-splat-map-texture-painting-dirt-removal-effect/ -- And I'll tell you that `blit_rect` is in the `Image` class (you can find it by searching on the official documentation), and it is not necessary, although it might help you depending your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this code I wrote for another [answer](https://godotengine.org/qa/12979/how-to-merge-two-png-files-during-runtime-and-save-to-disk):

```
# Create Image objects and load the png's
var body = Image()
var eyes = Image()
body.load("res://path_to_png")
eyes.load("res://path_to_png")  

# TRY1 - Draw the eyes over the body
body.blit_rect(eyes, Rect2(0,0,100,100), Vector2(15, 20))

# Save the image to new route
body.save_png("res://assets/generated/g_body.png")
```

`blit_rect()` takes a specified rectangle portion of an image and "blitz" (pastes) it on top of the other image as is **with** the alpha as well

However `blend_rect()` draws ontop of the other image **without** the alpha being copied over